# Адаптивная верстка flexbox

Tags: css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Как объединить 2 элемента справа в сетке, используя flexbox?

[image]

При уменьшении экрана сетка должна становиться такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть Вы хотите получить готовое решение по ТЗ? :)

Comment: Нет, вопрос стоит в том, как объединить 2 элемента справа на flexbox

Comment: последний блок в мобильной версии в самом низу?

Comment: [Описание всех свойств, там есть пример](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2926.html)

Comment: да, внизу.
Спасибо за информацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

.b-inner {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #999;
  height: 100vh;  
  width: 33.333%;
}
.b-item{
  height: 50vh;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .b-inner {
      width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-inner">
    <div class="b-item">

    </div>
    <div class="b-item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-inner">
    <div class="b-item">

    </div>
    <div class="b-item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-inner">

  </div>
</div>
```